# Notices for our traditions: Santa Questions

Tags: feature-request, on-topic, specific-tag, post-notices

I just voted to leave open a half-dozen Santa questions.

At this time I am aware of two kinds of "tradition" questions: Santa questions and "anatomically correct" questions.  Yes, they're all off-topic for a variety of reasons, but they're also popular and fun.  In other words, they're exceptions.

Rather than create lengthy meta descriptions for either of these two questions — and in an effort to keep people from voting to close many-year-old questions that are obviously in our tradition bracket — I would like to propose the creation of the following NOTICE for Santa-related questions.  This notice would be attached to all Santa questions past, present, and future to help people understand that they're a delightful exception to our normal rules.

> **Christmas Tradition:** Questions about Santa Clause are a Christmas tradition at Worldbuilding.SE.  Leniency is granted concerning our on-/off-topic rules.  Please only vote to close if the question is abusive, rude, a duplicate, or of very low quality.  See the [santa-claus](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/santa-claus) tag description for more information.

***I'm pretty sure I don't have privileges to create and attach these notices.  They're the same programmatic object as the [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science) notice.  This means I'm going to need the help of someone great and powerful to help me get this done.  Thanks!***

I've posted two answers, basically "Yes! Let's get this done!" and "No! We don't need that!"  Please comment to the question, not the answers, if you wish changes to be made.  Thanks!

Comment: @kingledion, no offence, but how can it be a duplicate when it's dealing with two different types of questions with potentially two completely different results?  Jeez.  If you don't think either issue is required, upvote the "No" answer and move on.

Comment: @kingledion Related, yes, but duplicate no. Besides if in future someone wanted to find Xmas traditions notices would they know to search for Notices for our traditions: Anatomically correct to find it had been discussed there? I sincerely doubt it. While I sympathize with the rationale to all discussions on a given topic in one place Firstly the topics are sufficiently divergent not to do so, and secondly, the necessary searching strategy requires detailed knowledge of those discussions. Without that, a good search won't find it. Impractical.

Comment: I think just about all points made in [my answer to the related *Anatomically correct* series question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5724/29) are equally valid here.

Comment: I agree with the duplicate suggestion.  Let's keep all the discussion in one place.  If the outcome is that we want a notice for Santa but not for the other series, we can separate them then.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, this is a good idea.**

A notice like this will help all users understand our Christmas tradition and avoid Santa-related questions ending up in the VTC queue.

Comment: Of course, yes! In every serious institution some levity is allowed -- on special occasions. Let Xmas be WB fun time. What's wrong with a Xmas tradition? Do we want to look like a bunch of constipated ideological purists? The majority of the human race can recognize when someone's having fun, despite being serious the rest of the year.

Answer (score 1):

**No, we don't need this.**

This will likely be more work than its worth and wouldn't stop new users from adding Santa questions to the VTC queues anyway.